# Node, Express, Ajax, Form Submission

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

Help, I'm Stuck! I am playing with a CRUD setup with Node Express but with AJAX post request. I have the read form working fine.

The form has one input filed which is a lookup email. AJAX post the form data with the following code

```
if ($("#rsvp-search-form").length) {
    $("#rsvp-search-form").validate({
        rules: {
           ...
        },

        messages: {
            ...
        },

        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $("#loader").css("display", "inline-block");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){ 
                    if (typeof data.redirect == 'string')
                    window.location = data.redirect;
                }
                ,
                error: function() {
                    $( "#loader").hide();
                    $( "#error").slideDown( "slow" );
                    setTimeout(function() {
                    $( "#error").slideUp( "slow" );
                    }, 5000);
                }
            });
            return false; // required to block normal submit since you used ajax
        }

    });
}
```

I have a express post route to '/' that returns a status with res.status(#).send() and the proper success/error block is executed based on the whether status # is 400 or 200.

Now on the update form I have the same basic setup with many more form inputs, but the AJAX code does not process the res.status(#).send() response by executing the proper success or error block, instead it is just loading a new page with the same url as the request was processed from.

The AJAX code request is similar to the top with difference of url:

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
                $("#loader").css("display", "inline-block");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    //The website when loaded has an invitation 
                    //object that is passed by express
                    url: "/rsvp/" +invitation._id,
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
                    dataType: 'application/json'
```

I verified that the proper post route is running and receiving the invitation._id. It returns res.staus(#).send() but the ajax does not process the success or error block it just redirects to the requesting url but does not actually render the url.

I don't know if it is just that the form is still processing the default action, if the response from express is not correct, etc etc

I hope I have been clear on my issue and someone knows what I am doing wrong here.

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update!

I got it working. Though the url with variable was correct and express was receiving the proper id, JS was throwing an error causing everything to crash. I never caught the error because the page would reload to the blank page and clear the console. I fixed it by saving the id in a hidden field when rendering the form and used that instead. Seems to have fixed the problem.

Thanks for looking!